# How to forget Wi-Fi network that has already been saved previously?

Tags: release-hera, wifi

I'm using elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera. I checked on Network Settings > Devices > Wireless. The triple vertical dots and Settings button didn't have the feature to forget these networks. I have like 50 public networks saved and would like to remove them using the GUI. Maybe I'm missing something because I can do this easily on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and type:

```
sudo nmtui
```

Use arrows to delete unwanted network. Be careful and do it slowly to remove only unwanted network.

Comment: This solves the problem. However, I wished it can be done from the GUI. This is certainly a UI/UX flaw in Hera.

Comment: Probably there is but I work every day with the terminal and do not want to turn on my laptop to provide the tutorial with images for people how to do it there. Besides this is the fastest way and works in every Linux with systemd and nmtui installed. The second is with nmcli but a little bit harder.